# Fastest way to interpolate between radians?

Tags: c++, interpolation, radians

So, I have radian angles without any range (-inf to +inf basically) and I need to interpolate these as quick as possible. If there any cookie cutter way to do this?

PS: I only need to interpolate 2 values at a time, so a+f*(b-a) basically

PPS: the output does NOT have to be in any specific range (-PI to PI or 0 to 2PI)

PPPS: The specific problem is how to do the wrapping of the values around -PI/+PI and their multiples most efficiently

Comment: Write the formula inline and trust your compiler.

Comment: Unclear question- please eloberate

Comment: Is your question "how to interpolate angles mathematically?" or "how to make my method (insert code) more efficient?"

Comment: What is wrong with `a+f*(b-a)`?

Comment: I'm not sure how to best manage the wrapping around the -PI/PI edge

Comment: what is the specific problem in your PPPS?

Comment: Is the specific problem about taking the *shortest* way between two angles?

Comment: Yes! I want to treat the values, no matter how often rotated, to be treated as if in the -pi/pi range, and interpolated accordingly

edit: So a:-19*pi-0.1 and b:-20pi+0.2 with f:0.5 should give me back pi*x+0.05

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**BETTER** Actually forget what I wrote first. You can simply do:

```
template<typename K>
K lerpAngle(K u, K v, K p) {
    return u + p*wrapMP(v - u);
}
```

where `wrapMP` moves an angle to the interval [-pi|+pi]. Both input `u` and `v` can be any radian angle and the result will also not be in a specific interval.

The idea is actually quite simple. Move your point of view to the point `u` such that `u=0`. Now `v` can be arbitrary as angles are not normalized, but we just wrap the distance `v-u = v` to [-pi|+pi] and walk by the given percentage `p` into that direction.

---

**OLD (and inefficient)** I wrote this code once:

```
template<typename K>
K lerpAngle(K u, K v, K p) {
    K a = wrap2Pi(u);
    K b = wrap2Pi(v);
    K d = b - a;
    if(d < -PI) {
        b += 2*PI;
    }
    if(d > +PI) {
        b -= 2*PI;
    }
    return wrap2Pi(a + p*(b - a));
}
```

where `wrap2i` moves an angle to the interval [0,2*pi[.

Comment: Why do you `static_cast<K>(p)` when `p` is already of type `K`?

Comment: shouldn't it be 

    if(d >= +PI) {
        b -= 2*PI;
    }

Comment: @leemes: Totally right! This was a leftover as in the original code `p` could have a different type.

Comment: @user1071988: I think it does not matter. If the distance is exactly PI (i.e. 180 degree), than you can interpolate either going left or right.

Answer (score 3):

First, "normalize" your input angles so they're in a specific range, like `(-π, π]`. If you do this already, skip this part.

Then, take their difference. If the absolute value of this difference is greater than `π` then adjust one of the inputs by adding / subtracting `2π` such that the absolute value of the difference becomes less or equal to `π`.

Then simply interpolate between those two values.

If the output of this interpolation should always be in the range `(-π, π]` again (note: it probably doesn't have to, depending on where you need this angle), then add / subtract `2π` again if it's not.

Comment: Okay, that's what I thought, there is no better way to do this :(

Comment: I guess not, and Danvil's answer is pretty much the same, but code instead of words ;)